# How can I find the index of the greatest value in an array then target and return a different value with the same index

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

I have a JSON payload shown below. I want to loop through and find the one with the highest value for "numUsed". Then, I want to display that number along with the associated "type". For the example below, I'd like to end up with:

"Your favourite benefit was Benefit C, you used it 18 times!"

In its final state, I'd like to disregard the "All Benefits" section.

```
"Benefits": [
                        {
                            "type": "Benefit A",
                            "dollarSavings": 0,
                            "timeSavings": 0,
                            "numUsed": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Benefit B",
                            "dollarSavings": 89.85,
                            "timeSavings": 47700,
                            "numUsed": 15
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Benefit C",
                            "dollarSavings": 99.85,
                            "timeSavings": 46700,
                            "numUsed": 18
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "All Benefits",
                            "dollarSavings": 189.70,
                            "timeSavings": 94400,
                            "numUsed": 38
                        }
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't even tried. Stack Overflow is not a writting code service.

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried, and maybe also link to a question or two that you have referenced in trying to address (and what doesn't work when you try what they suggest).  It can feel time consuming doing that when posting questions, but it helps guide people who want to help you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP right, thanks for checking me on that. I'd seen questions posed in the same before so. Anyway, I solved it, posting my solution here for posterity

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
{% assign numbers = data.Benefits | sort: 'numUsed'  %}
    {% for nums in numbers %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% assign benefits = data. data.Benefits | sort: 'numUsed'  %}
    {% for name in benefits %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% assign numsize = numbers | size %}
    {% assign numsizeminustwo = numsize | minus: 2 %}
    {% assign secondlasttype = benefits[{{numsizeminustwo}}].type %}
    {% assign secondlastnumber = numbers[{{numsizeminustwo}}].numUsed | floor %}
    
    Your favorite benefit this year was {{benefit_name}}, you used it {{secondlastnumber}} times
```